# Google sheets countif cell not empty AND background color not white

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an online spreadsheet that I maintain that tracks all live local channels in each market for streaming TV providers (Sling, DIRECTV NOW, PS Vue, Youtube TV, Philo, etc)

http://streambuzz.net/streaming-tv-local-channels/

I am using the following formula to include cells in the count of totals:

```
=countif(B5:B199,"<>")
```

Each non empty cell will have a logo representing one of the major network affiliates (ABC, CBS, FOX, NBC, CW, MyTV, Telemundo)

However, I need to be able to track when a station that was active suddenly goes off the air and becomes on demand only (usually due to failed retrans negotiations) such as happened this week when Playstation Vue customers lost all Tribune owned Fox stations (about a dozen major cities affected)

In that case, I want to highlight the cell with a white background but leave the Fox logo there to indicate a special case.

So, long question short, how can I append the formula condition to count the cell only if its non empty AND has a white background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom function like this:

```
function checkw(row1, row2, column) { // input is range of cells like "A1:A25"
    var counter = 0;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    for (var row = row1; row <= row2; row++) {
        var cellobj = sheet.getRange(row, column);
        var cellval = cellobj.getValue();
        var currentColor = cellobj.getBackground();
        if (currentColor === "#ffffff" && cellval === "") {
            counter++;
        }
        Logger.log(counter);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

and call it from a cell in your spreadsheet like this:
=checkw(2,22,1)

The first two args are the beginning and ending rows. The third arg is the column.

Comment: If you haven't done Google sheets scripting before, LMK and I can help you get going.